# How to convert user entered string as NSDate object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am taking input from user as string and want to store it in date format but after printing back to console it give me `NULL`...

Here is what I did:

```
MyLog(@"\nPlease Enter Date");
scanf("%s",cDate);

stringDate= [NSString stringWithCString:cDate encoding:1];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat  = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate * incomeDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:sDate];

MyLog(@"Date Entered is %@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:incomeDate]);
```

Comment: I think it should be  NSDate * incomeDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:stringDate];

Comment: isn't **sDate** should be ***stringDate*** or vice-versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are entering date string in **dd-MM-yyyy** as i can see you are using `[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to convert from string to date, but make sure you use same date format which you are taking input from user

```
    NSString *stringtoconvert = @"13-09-2014";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:stringtoconvert];
    MyLog(@"Date Entered is %@",date);
```